# Python text command doesn't output the string data on the actual text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just learning about the text file function in python 3 by using website called, https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/ although the program seems collect, the text data in the python's programming screen doesn't show in the actual text data file.
Is there any mistake I've ever made in the text program below?
The version of my Python is Python 3.7.5 .

```
File = open("NewTextFile.Txt", "a")
string = "ABC"
File.write(string)
File.close
```

Comment: Maybe the file is not closed properly. Try `File.close()`; note the parentheses `()`. For this kind of task, it is often advised to use `with` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much j1 lee, it was my silly mistake that leads by my carelessness.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `()` at `File.close`, so the file is not properly closed. Try putting `()`.

Often it is recommended to use `with` clause:

```py
with open('NewTextFile.Txt', 'a') as file:
    string = 'ABC'
    file.write(string)
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly close the file here. The file is kept open within the clause. Once your python program exits the `with` clause, the file is automatically closed; in this way your program gets less prone to mistakes.

For more information, see a relevant python doc:

> It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point.
>
> — https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files